# Unity Scene Window GUI Buttons are not rendering properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container, unity-ui

I recently installed unity 2021.3.2f1, everything is fine, but the scene window buttons are not rendering properly, mainly there icons.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

NOTE: My PC does not have external graphics card, and I am running 2nd gen i3 with integraded graphics along with 8gb ram.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnCFg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like, and looks like **your computer is having trouble loading Unity**. With the specs that you shared, that is not surprising. Also, this questions would be better asked at the [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/) where paid Unity staff can assist you.

### Possible solutions:

1. Try to use the previous LTS versions to see if you suffer the same issues (if possible for your project). If you see the same results with previous versions then it seems like your hardware is the issue. If you can run previous LTS versions without issue then there may be a bug in the latest release.
2. I hate to say it, but without upgrading your computer, you may need to do the basics of tech. Turn it off and on. Uninstall and reinstall. Leave for 15m-2 hours to wait for it to load. Currently, I use an i7 9900k and 64gb ram with no external graphics card with no issues or loading times. But years back I had an i5 with 4gb ram and I could barely open Unity and every button press took ages to load.
3. Your best bet of course, might be to upgrade your CPU. (By the way, the graphics card is not the issue here as many CPU's have a built in graphics cards and as you can render graphics then yours must have a built in graphics card as well.)